# get all cookies related to current tab

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying various things now but cannot get it to work. I want **all** cookies related to the current tab (ie also those on a different domain eg google). The below only gives me those matching the tab domain. Setting getAll({}) gives me all cookies related to any page visited.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var cookies2=[];
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true,active:true},function(tab) {
      console.log(tab[0]);
      chrome.cookies.getAll({url:tab[0].url},function(cookies) {
        for (var i in cookies) {
            console.log(cookies[i].domain,cookies[i].path,cookies[i].name);
        }
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Cookies are bound to URLs, not to tabs. If you want to get a list of cookies for all URLs for which a page has made requests (including external domains), you should intercept http-requests, collect all URLs and then call `cookies.getAll` for all of them.

Answer (score 7):

What exactly do you mean by "all cookies related to current tab"?

Any resource loaded over the network could be associated with a cookie. If you just want to get the cookies for all frames within the tab, then use the [`chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#method-getAllFrames) method to get a list of URLs associated with a tab. Here's a very naive method of getting all cookies.

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    currentWindow: true,
    active: true
}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({
        tabId: tabs[0].id
    }, function(details) {
        // Get unique list of URLs
        var urls = details.reduce(function(urls, frame) {
            if (urls.indexOf(frame.url) === -1)
                urls.push(frame.url);
            return urls;
        }, []);
        // Get all cookies
        var index = 0;
        var cookies = [];
        urls.forEach(function(url) {
            chrome.cookies.getAll({
                url: url
            }, function(additionalCookies) {
                cookies = cookies.concat(additionalCookies);
                if (++index === urls.length) {
                    // Collected all cookies!
                    // TODO: Use cookies.
                    // Note: The array may contain duplicate cookies!
                }
            }); // chrome.cookies.getAll
        }); // urls.forEach
    }); // chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames
}); // chrome.tabs.query
```

The previous method is naive, because the resulting array of cookies might contain duplicate entries (e.g. if the page contains `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/index.htm`, then you'll get two entries for a cookie on `.example.com`).
There are many ways to filter duplicates in a JavaScript array, you can see some methods in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates).

If you want to literally get all cookies associated with a tab, then you need to collect them using the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) API. Use the `webRequest` events to detect network requests and the `Cookie` request header and `Set-Cookie` and `Set-Cookie2` response headers. You have to manually parse the cookie though.

If you want to quickly see all cookies associated with a tab (frames only, like the first method), you can also open the developer tools and look at Resources -> Cookies).

[image]
<sup>(image source: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resources)</sup>